# как извлечь ключ соответствующий значению, удовлетворяющему заданному условию в словаре

Tags: python

Есть несколько ордеров, то запрос `ActiveOrders` присылает ответ.
Как выудить по `'type': 'buy'` его `order_id` (`'335740211'`)?

```
{'335710271': {'pair': 'usd_rur', 'type': 'sell', 'amount': 1.0, 'rate': 63.0, 'timestamp_created': 1528910110, 'status': 0},
 '335729928': {'pair': 'usd_rur', 'type': 'sell', 'amount': 3.74039039, 'rate': 62.0, 'timestamp_created': 1528911179, 'status': 0},
 '335740211': {'pair': 'usd_rur', 'type': 'buy', 'amount': 1.0, 'rate': 56.0, 'timestamp_created': 1528911795, 'status': 0}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
keys_ = [key for key, val in orders.items() if val['type'] == 'buy']
```

или - более общее:

```
type_ = 'buy'
keys_ = [key for key, val in orders.items() if val['type'] == type_]
```

`key` - это `order_id`, `val` - это ему принадлежащий словарь и `val['type']` - значение этого словаря для ключа `'type'`.

Вес код:

```
orders =  \
    {'335710271': {'pair': 'usd_rur', 'type': 'sell', 'amount': 1.0, 'rate': 63.0, 'timestamp_created': 1528910110, 'status': 0},
     '335729928': {'pair': 'usd_rur', 'type': 'sell', 'amount': 3.74039039, 'rate': 62.0, 'timestamp_created': 1528911179, 'status': 0},
     '335740211': {'pair': 'usd_rur', 'type': 'buy', 'amount': 1.0, 'rate': 56.0, 'timestamp_created': 1528911795, 'status': 0}}

type_ = 'buy'
keys_ = [key for key, val in orders.items() if val['type'] == type_]

print(keys_)
print(keys_[0])    // Первый член списка
```

Вывод:

> ```
> ['335740211']
> 335740211
> ```

Надо осознать, что может выть больше `order_id`-ов (например для типа `'sell'` в вашем примере) - потому я построил *список всех подходящих* `order_id`-ов.

Comment: да всё правильно, а если их больше будет со временем этому коду не важно будет,пройдётся по всем элементам?

Comment: спасибо за развёрнутый ответ

Comment: Как иначе обнаружить все подходящее `order_id`-ы?

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) (предназначен для обработки табличных данных).

Исходный словарь:

```
In [23]: d
Out[23]:
{'335710271': {'pair': 'usd_rur',
  'type': 'sell',
  'amount': 1.0,
  'rate': 63.0,
  'timestamp_created': 1528910110,
  'status': 0},
 '335729928': {'pair': 'usd_rur',
  'type': 'sell',
  'amount': 3.74039039,
  'rate': 62.0,
  'timestamp_created': 1528911179,
  'status': 0},
 '335740211': {'pair': 'usd_rur',
  'type': 'buy',
  'amount': 1.0,
  'rate': 56.0,
  'timestamp_created': 1528911795,
  'status': 0}}
```

из словаря создадим DataFrame:

```
In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame(d).T

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
            amount     pair rate status timestamp_created  type
335710271        1  usd_rur   63      0        1528910110  sell
335729928  3.74039  usd_rur   62      0        1528911179  sell
335740211        1  usd_rur   56      0        1528911795   buy
```

теперь можно легко найти все что нам нужно:

```
In [29]: out = df[df['type'] == 'buy'].index.tolist()

In [30]: print(out)
['335740211']
```

Comment: как сложновато ((

Answer (score 0):

Почему не сделать банальный перебор элементов циклом for? Да, относительно долго, но просто. Например:

```
result = []
for key in A:
    B = A[key]
    if 'buy' in B: result.append(key)
```

Или как-то так, со словарями еще не приходилось иметь дело, сам язык только начал изучать.

Comment: возвращает  [] [] [] три таких пустых ответа